# Git is showing (modify/delete) conflict while using the revert command

Tags: git, github, conflict

I made an empty repository and created a file and committed it and then I made a change and committed it again.
Now I tried to revert to the first commit by using git revert command but it is showing an error saying

**git revert 022381f9ba075b7c3549e18340837119c833c12c
CONFLICT (modify/delete): file1.txt deleted in (empty tree) and modified in HEAD.  Version HEAD of file1.txt left in tree.
error: could not revert 022381f... Added file1.txt and added text to it**

I am expecting to revert it to the first commit (022381f9ba075b7c3549e18340837119c833c12c) but it is showing an error

```
vanum@DESKTOP-BF2U9VF MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/project (master)
$ git log
commit e6cc90a1c488288ac5d6fb626257057f77d50b39 (HEAD -> master)
Author: vanumdaniel7 <vanumdaniel7@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 20 22:22:43 2023 +0530

    Made a change to the file file1.txt

commit 022381f9ba075b7c3549e18340837119c833c12c
Author: vanumdaniel7 <vanumdaniel7@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 20 22:22:10 2023 +0530

    Added file1.txt and added text to it

vanum@DESKTOP-BF2U9VF MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/project (master)
$ git revert 022381f9ba075b7c3549e18340837119c833c12c
CONFLICT (modify/delete): file1.txt deleted in (empty tree) and modified in HEAD.  Version HEAD of file1.txt left in tree.
error: could not revert 022381f... Added file1.txt and added text to it
hint: After resolving the conflicts, mark them with
hint: "git add/rm <pathspec>", then run
hint: "git revert --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit with "git revert --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git revert",
hint: run "git revert --abort".

vanum@DESKTOP-BF2U9VF MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/project (master|REVERTING)
$
```

[image]

Comment: 0223 added the file but e6cc changed the file so 0223 can't be reverted because e6cc depends on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding about what commit to specify with the `git revert` command:

`git revert` does **not** revert everything *up to* the given commit.

`git revert` instead only reverts the changes of the given commit, by creating a new commit with the opposite changes.

So what you want to do it revert the second commit, to effectively change the code back to what it was before.

```
git revert e6cc90a1c488288ac5d6fb626257057f77d50b39
```

After that you'll have three commits in your history: The initial commit, the second commit and a third commit that reverts the changes of the second commit.

**OR**

If you want to move the local branch back by one commit you can use `git reset HEAD~`.

Note, that is **not** a good idea if you've already pushed your second commit,
because it will return next time you pull. (Unless you force-push, but that's a topic on its own).
If you pushed already, then `git revert` is usually the better option.

---

Side-Note: You can abort your current revert with `git revert --abort`
(I just realized git hinted at that in your screenshot, but I'll leave this note here anyway; just in case)